# Can't Connect to (or start?) Google Cloud Compute Instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

I attempted to restart my Windows instance (using the Start menu), but haven't been able to connect to it. After a few hours of waiting, I also tried using the Reboot button in the Google Developers Console. That didn't work either. I can't RDP into it, or even ping it. However, when I look at the instance in the GDC, it's been steady at 27% CPU usage for the duration. Anyone know what's going on or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run this gcutil command to reset the instance: gcutil --project=[project-id] resetinstance [instance-name]

If this has no effect, a suggestion would be to delete the instance **without deleting the boot disk** and then create a new instance with that disk. This will ensure that you get a fresh instance without losing any of your previous data.

Comment: Thanks. That appeared to do the same thing as clicking the Reboot button. Do you know how long it should take for a Windows Server 2008 instance to start? Also, I use this for a production environment, so files are manipulated on the instance daily. Isn't the boot disk what is set up initially, and then remains static? Or is it just the drive that the instance runs from? My concern is that I'll lose my work.

Comment: As long as the boot disk isn't deleted, none of the data will be lost. I don't know how long it might take for a Windows Server 2008 to restart, but when rebooting fails the only thing left to do is to recreate the instance.

Comment: Thank you! About to try that. In your experience, how often does rebooting fail? This might be a factor that drives me to AWS, as happy as I am with how well the Google Compute Cloud works otherwise.

Comment: Rebooting can fail if there's a config issue on the instance, which can be solved by recreating it.